# Custom Menu for Team / User in MS CRM 2011 Online

Tags: user-interface, menu, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Does anyone know how to customize the menu in MS CRM 2011 (Cloud) so that certain options (e.g. Marketing) do not appear for some users / teams but continue to appear for the Administrators or Power Users?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean the menu or sitemap?  The menu refers to the "File" menu.  Site map is for the left hand side of entities, workplace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the sitemap, you'll want to use the "Privilege" rule.

Here's some documentation on the sitemap:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334430.aspx

Here's an example of using the privilege rule to show/hide areas:
http://worldofdynamics.blogspot.com/2012/04/dynamics-crm-2011-restricthide-settings.html